# Use DDNS domain for multiple machines and ports

Tags: networking, iptables, domain, ddns

I have the following setup: 
1st) a Raspberry Pi with ssh and ftp in my home lan, which I access from outside via a dynamic DNS domain. 
2nd) a website on a webspace with a free hoster which is connect to a proper domain by another hoster (a record). 
3rd) another Pi at my parents house which manly works as a backup for the first pi but also as a vpn for remote maintenance. Again it's access by another dynamic dns domain.

To sum it up: 3 devices, 3 locations, 3 domains. 
What I want to achieve: access all of them on one domain, preferably the proper one used for my webspace.

My ideas so far: since the hoster of the proper domain supports DDNS as well, I though of binding it to my first pi. This would (based on the port it is accessed) redirect the connection to the actual webspace or the second pi. Is this possible? Maybe with ip tables? Maybe with a private dns (probably not, since it's only used for the address translation not for ports)? Maybe it's similar to load balancing? How would I do that?

Example configuration: port 80 of the domain should be connected to the webspace, port 22 to pi 1, Port 1234 to pi 2 with everything available on one domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum it up: DNS doesn't know about splitting ports up.  Simply put, DNS connects Names to either an IP address (A Record) or another name (CNAME record).  What occurs at the port level at each 'location' is the router's responsibility.

The simplest thing that you can do is create sub-domains on your 'proper' domain name for location A and C and connect them to the actual locations using CNAME records pointing to the existing dynamic DNS records.  That would look something like this:

> locationA.domain.com  CNAME  absdcslwekjnds.dynamicDNS.com
>
> locationC.domain.com  CNAME  skjdkfljdlfjdl.dynamicDNS.com

That's basically saying for example that locationA.domain.com uses the same IP address as absdcslwekjnds.dynamicDNS.com (and the IP for that is set using dynamic DNS client).  therefore locationA.domain.com always points to the same place as absdcslwekjnds.dynamicDNS.com.

To take this to the next level (towards the direction where your example was headed) you would need to have the domain itself point to a single location, the other 2 locations would need to be connected to the first location via VPN. The router at the first location could then route to the devices at the other locations because they are connected via VPN.

That sounds great, but if you go that direction, don't forget to build in a method for when the VPN goes down or gets disconnected.  Say you're at location C and the location A VPN goes offline. Now you need a way to direct connect to A (or drive over there) to get the VPN back online.

In short if you just want names on the proper domain to point to different locations use sub-domains as described above and be done with it.  If you want to build a system using VPN's and Routing with a single router for educational purposes then knock yourself out, it is possible, but be aware that your system using home grade equipment (as opposed to enterprise grade equipment) and the general internet for connectivity (as opposed to dedicated interconnects) will be fragile.  It will break from time to time and you may or may not be able to fix what broke remotely.

Oh, and I didn't even address security when taking it to the next level but don't forget to take that into account too.

(and BTW... make certain that ftp on ANY computer that is routeable from the internet is disabled and the port closed. The ftp protocol is one of the oldest and most insecure protocols still in use today. Use SFTP instead.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I thought way to complex and somehow didn't see the easy way to just use subdomains. However I might try the option with routing stuff anyway just to see what's possible but you're right it might be too complex and too unstable. In regards to ftp: it was just a synonym for a sync and file server but since that is a little more complex because it's p2p based, I decided to boil it down to ftp instead.